# VB.net POST via HttpWebRequest

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, post, httpwebrequest

I am trying to use the following code in order to send a command to a Arduino Ethernet micro controller on my LAN:

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://192.178.47.19:19/?r=")
Dim POST As String = "r1"

request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "text/html"
request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
request.ContentLength = POST.Length
request.KeepAlive = True

Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
Dim postBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(POST)
requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
requestStream.Close()
```

However, I am getting the error on line:

```
Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
```

saying this:

*The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.*

Using just jQuery and AJAX:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

  $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        async : true,
        type: "POST",
        headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
        url: "http://192.178.47.19:19/?r=" + whatsBeingSent,
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "text/html",
        dataType: "html",
        success: OnSuccessCallArduino,
        error: OnErrorCallArduino
  });
```

Using that code above works just fine (inside a browser of course)

So what would I be missing in order to get it working in VB.net?

Comment: The. Net code is posting to a completely different ip address than the jQuery ajax code. Is this a typo is your post?

Comment: No, i just forgot to change it.

Comment: The issue could be that you are not passing "r=r1"as the query string in your. Net Web request. You are posting two different requests in your. Net Web request and your ajax call.

Comment: For example, the query string in your ajax call is "r=r1" but in your. Net code is "r=" and then you are sending a post with value of "r1" which is separate from the query string.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. I am using a jQuery AJAX call in browser client to access an aspx file which runs a function that generates a WebRequest response. This normally works without issues. However, if the function uses a WebRequest to access a different server, the response is good but never returns to the original AJAX call and the application hangs.

Browser AJAX:

```
    $.ajax({ dataType: "text", type: "POST", url: "WSProfile.aspx", async: false, data: { oper: 'FunctionSpecification', Data1: d1, Data2: d2 }, success: function (msg) { alert(msg); } });
```

WSProfile.Aspx:

```
    Dim d1 As Text = Request.Form("Data1")
    Dim d2 As Text = Request.Form("Data2")

    Function getResponse(d1, d2)

    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://urlname.com")
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim postData As String = "data1=" & d1 & "&data2=" & d2
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim response As WebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim Status As String = CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)

    Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd())
    Response.Flush()
```

The call to the other URL returns a response but the Response.Write of the original call to the `.aspx` file never returns the data to the jQuery AJAX call.